# Why are all road bike frames now squashed parallelograms?

Tags: road-bike, frames, seatpost

I am currently shopping for a road bike and have questions about current frame designs.  My height is 6'3" and decade(s) ago I always liked frame designs for which the top of the seatstays joined at the top of the seat tube, along with the top tube.  A purely horizontal top tube was also more aesthetic looking as well.  Nowadays, frames look like a squashed parallelogram, which is likely due to weight-saving considerations -- since less framing is required(?)

The question is: why do almost all seatstays now join in the middle of the seat tube, which places more stress on the top of the seat tube?  Further, for a taller-heavier person, the seat post must be elevated, causing more stress on the top of the seat tube.  I think if the seatstays joined at the top of the seat tube, there would be less stress on the seat tube when the seat post is highly elevated.

In light of the above considerations, does anyone manufacture a more parallelogram frame that's not squashed, and with seatstays that join at the top of the seat tube, with a horizontal top tube?

Comment: Surly makes plenty of traditional frames with horizontal top tubes. I'm sure you'll find a suitable bike from their catalog.

Comment: A lot of steel frames are a more traditional design (related to @juhist's point). Some of the major manufacturers of steel frames also make carbon frames with more traditional geometry

Comment: A long seatpost can flex and act as suspension. I think seatpost diameters have even *decreased* in recent years (while all other tube diameters have generally increased since forever) to allow for more flex.

Comment: I believe the proper term for what you describe is compact frame. Dropped seat stays, mentioned in adam’s answer, are distinct from compact geometry. In theory, you could have someone build a level top tube frame with dropped stays.

Comment: In addition to Surly, their more expensive sibling All-City has traditional frame aesthetics.

Comment: @Michael 27.2mm is still the norm, but D-shaped posts are nothing special now and Cannondale has reverted to 25.4mm for some models.

Comment: I looked at Surly - they look like great steel commute bikes. Gut feeling is that they are Pacific-Northwest?

Comment: @user0123456789: Surly, All-City, Salsa, and several others are the house brands of Minnesota based QBP, the 800 pound gorilla of bike shop suppliers. Minnesota designed, fabricated in Taiwan.  Surlys are great, practical bikes. I own two cross-checks.

Comment: Surlys are unnecessarily heavy in my opinion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sloping top tubes started with mountain bikes, and were brought over to road bikes by Giant, following a design from Mike Burrows. Partly because a perpendicular joint between the seat tube and top tube is more efficient at transmitting loads, and partly so the manufacturer can get away with making fewer frame sizes.

There really aren't that many bikes with dropped seat stays—that's mostly a feature of aero racing bikes, and supposedly increases comfort.

All the major manufacturers have modelled the forces on their bikes extensively. The liability of an underbuilt bike is not worth it to them, although there have been some notable failures with superlight bikes, where there's clearly not much safety margin built in. Aesthetic considerations are absolutely reasonable, but I wouldn't avoid one of these newer-geometry bikes out of fear they would fail.

In any case, as mentioned in the comments, there are lots of steel bikes with traditional geometry. And Cannondale was a notable holdout on horizontal top tubes until recently. If you're really tall, Rivendell even makes bikes with double top tubes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- very helpful.  I am sure FEA (finite element analysis) is used nowadays to model stress/harmonics during frame design, since CAD-CAM was not available to the public before the early 90s.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted and didn't notice for a bit and can't fix :(

Comment: This is an outrage! Seriously, not a big deal.

Comment: @whatsisname If the answer is edited, you can change you vote...

Comment: Wouldn't the current frame design (dropped seat stays at seat tube - smaller triangle) resulting in greater power transfer (see @Jeff) and less shock to the seat (more flex to the top of the seat tube) be a remarkable discovery?  Who initially made that discovery? - had to be via CAD-CAM modelling.  What I can't understand is the skimping part of making fewer frame sizes.   Have BMW/Audi/Mercedes/Porsche stopped making a model because it's too expensive to offer so many series/models - No!   Maybe bike frame designs became like phone apps -- too many -- so only survivors are in business.

Comment: @user0123456789: car manufacturers absolutely reuse "cars" between different marques, example the Audi Q7, Porsche Cayenne, and VW Touareg are all basically the same car with slightly different bodies and features. All the different car groups have platforms that multiple car models share. It would be way too expensive for each brand to have it's own unique platforms. More frame sizes for a model is more engineering time, more tooling, more inventory to move, etc.

Comment: @user0123456789 Cars do not come in different sizes. That’s the distinction. Every size needs its own welding jigs/molds/frame elements, components such as forks need to be cut according to frame size, etc. Factor in bikes’ much lower sales volume and its a big savings not offering 7 sizes or whatever. On the extreme end, some niche mountain bikes are only available in either small-medium or medium-large.

Comment: I did a quick check and looks like Giant has 6 and Trek for 8 sizes for their road bikes. So the argument about reducing inventory doesn't really hold.

Comment: @MaplePanda cars do come in different sizes, and I'm not just talking about estate vs hatchback (though that's also true, e.g. Ford: Focus Wagon is 30cm longer and 20cm taller than the base model).  Instead, in a matrix of size and spec, cars apply the model name to the size and the spec (component level) is fine tuning, while bikes tend to attach a name to a specification and the size is a detail.  OK car size isn't primarily about occupant size, but if you're tall it is, or even more if you've got tall passengers  sitting in the back (as a teenager my head touched the ceiling in small cars)

Comment: @ojs That was definitely a reason given when we started seeing sloped top tubes, but that was a while ago. It may be that manufacturers realized that bike fit is important enough that many sizes are worth the expense.

Comment: @ojs: Trek is a huge manufacturer that can move a lot more bikes, but also many of their less expensive models, such as their hybrids, only come in 4 sizes. Smaller manufacturers also have fewer sizes for many models.

Comment: @whatsisname did they come in more sizes back when top tubes were horizontal?

Comment: (Spoiler: I looked up an 1991 catalog, it has 8 sizes road bikes and 4 or 5 for MTBs and hybrids. I want to see how this is turned to support the idea that there are fewer sizes now than there used to be)

Comment: As far as I can tell, when the Burrows-designed TCR and Defy hit the market (1997?), they were offered in 4 sizes, with interchangeable seatposts to accommodate different heights. Here's [a little more about it](https://inrng.com/2012/05/the-ancestor-of-your-bike/).

Comment: The link doesn't mention the 4 sizes or interchangeable seatposts. Anyway, I think a bit more truthful answer might be that the inventors of the sloped top tube thought that they could get away with smaller inventory but ended up having the same amount of choices than before.

Answer (score 9):

The modern design has one really important feature for the frame makers and sellers: They only need to stock very few different frame sizes, the rest is adjusted by selecting a suitable seat post.

However, this design is a massive step backwards in terms of structural robustness of the entire bike: While the frame's strength is not reduced significantly, the forces on the seat post are increased significantly. The longer the seat post, the longer the lever that the weight of the rider has to make it bend/break at the seat post clamp. As such, long seat posts must not only be heavier due to their increased length, they must also be heavier because the material must be thicker. This weight increase definitely eats up all the weight savings that might be in the frame itself.

Seat posts are not particularly prone to failure. Manufacturers know that they are a single point of failure, and generally make them robust enough to endure all normal usage. Nevertheless, they can and do break, which is why i prefer the classical horizontal top tube form. However, the modern design has the advantage of not putting your privates in danger when you happen to loose the pedals, or break the bottom bracket axle (this happens, too). So it's basically up to you to decide which design you like better, and how much importance you put on the frame design part.

Comment: That's a great comment about having to stock only a few frame sizes - economy of scale.  Generally speaking, in terms of the newer squashed parallelogram design, if the top tube is lower at the seat tube, then rider height is less of a problem (crushing your privates when standing).  The historically termed "women's bikes" never had a horizontal bar, so height and privates were not an issue.   Lack of robustness is also key - which means a common theme for frame design results in frames that won't perform optimally in a variety of environments/conditions.  You nailed it.

Comment: Seatposts aren't prone to failure, but the bolts holding the saddle definitely are! Ask me how I know!

Comment: @Mohair Ask me how I know that seat posts can, and do fail! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The seat stays being attached further down the seat tube increases frame compliance--essentially a little extra frame flex at the seat tube-- to help smooth road & gravel vibrations and bumps.  The design also shrinks the rear triangle which actually enhances overall frame stiffness.  Again, the increased compliance is at the seat tube while the smaller rear triangle yields an overall stiffer frame. Another perk of the dropped seat stays is the enhanced aerodynamics where the smaller triangle improves air flow from the stays to the rear wheel.

The smaller, stiffer rear triangle improves power transfer to the rear wheel.  Some manufacturers are claiming improved times over 40km--like the best part of a minute improvement.  The design has been found to be faster which is most certainly a consumer demand.  Aesthetically, there is some criticism, and manufacturers are looking at comfort yielding alternatives to dropped stays.  Trek, notably, follows the traditional seat-stay design but decouples the seat tube from road forces with their IsoSpeed system. Cannondale places an actual bearing pivot at the seat stay--seat-tube junction on at least one carbon model.

Today's bikes have improved performance over several metrics.  The dropped seat stays are not the entire reason for the improvement, but are a definite factor in the besting yesterday's measurements.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that the smaller rear triangle yields an overall stiffer frame?

Comment: I follow what you are saying about the smaller triangle in the rear resulting in faster times.   It's logical, because if the frame was like a very flexible bow (bow & arrow) the power transfer to the back wheel would be greater.  Whereas, if it's a right-triangle in the rear (90 degrees), the entire frame is too rigid with much less flexibility.  Power transfer issue you raise relates to the harmonics I mentioned in comments to @Adam Rice - which can be optimized during FEA.

Comment: @user0123456789 Not sure which right triangle you are referring to. Generally, high stiffness is regarded as desirable to improve power transfer.

Comment: Has there ever been a gimmick that hasn't been claimed to increase lateral stiffness, vertical compliance and overall speed?

Comment: @cmaster - reinstate monica "Ribble’s Head of Product Design Jamie Burrow lists numerous benefits (of a smaller rear triangle) 'The benefits over a traditional rear triangle are: ... (3) smaller triangles are stiffer, keeping the rear triangle stiffer and maintaining power transfer to the back wheel.'" from Road.cc article, ["What are dropped seatstays good for?"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/road.cc/content/feature/what-are-dropped-seatstays-good-267053%3famp)

Comment: I have to call marketing-BS on at least the “overall frame stiffness” point. That's affected by so many different design details of the frame that it's meaningless to link it to specifically the rear triangle size. It most certainly is possible to build a very stiff horizontal–top-tube bike. What I can get behind is that the dropped seatstays are a way to make the bike more compliant towards the seat (_less_ stiff!) without making the rest of the bike floppy too. The point about smaller triangles being stiffer is generally false unless you shrink the _long_ sides, i.e. the chain+seatstays.

Comment: I like the phrase "*keeping* the rear triangle stiff*er* (sic)", emphasis mine. I also note that the direction of this quote is contrary to the direction of the article around it: The article basically says that frames have gotten very stiff, and that dropping the seat stays below the top tube allows the seat tube to flex *more* while keeping the frame's lateral stiffness intact. Which, by and large, matches my expectation on the matter. The Burrow quote, on the other hand, sounds - *weird*.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Pythagoras! If you lower the junction of the seat stays and seat tube then you do indeed shrink one of the long sides.

Comment: @AndyP not sure where you see Pythagoras here, since there is no right angle (presumably you mean at the bottom bracket between chainstay and seat tube, but that's almost always acute). It's still true that the seatstays are typically the longest side, and they do certainly get a bit shorter as you drop them, but simultaneously you also shrink the _shortest_ side (seat tube between BB and seat stays), and that's what's detrimental for stiffness.

Comment: (That's not to say you can't also build a pretty stiff bike with very acute rear triangle. Some competition trials bikes are astonishingly stiff despite being almost line-shaped, but there the tradeoff is: you want the bike to be as slim as possible for movement freedom, while still being able to withstand a drop from several meters. Stiffness is mostly a side-effect of _strength_ here.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes, I was indeed simplifying the chainstay/seatpost junction to be a right angle.  I'm not sure how shrinking the short side reduces stiffness - feel free to pop into bicycles chat to educate me though - comments probably not the best place for mechanical engineering lessons :)

Comment: Interesting: My first idea was that a "stretched" frame with short seat tube *increases* frame flexibility: The extreme would be basically two very long-stretched triangles with a very short seat tube which should have significant vertical elasticity. Is that not so?